# CORS Fails with Safari 10.1.2 and Google Storage

Tags: safari, cors, google-cloud-storage

**Platforms**:

Tested on iPhone iOS 10, macOS Sierra v10.12.6
Safari v10.1.2 (Safari v10.1.1 and below don't seem to have this problem, and neither do Chrome nor Firefox)

**Description**:

We're having a problem saving a photo through Google Cloud Storage. From the web inspector, we see that we're making a OPTIONS request to http://storage.googleapis.com/..., but we receive an empty response.  Whereas, in other browsers or in other versions of Safari, we don't see a OPTIONS request, only the POST request. We've verified that our CORS configuration on the Google Cloud Storage bucket allows our origin.

Our request headers for the OPTIONS request look like this:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
Referer: <referrer>
Origin: <origin>
Accept: */
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

From what we can see in the Safari devtools, there are no response headers, and the response is empty. As for the status code, there's no status code from what we can see in Safari devtools, but when we were using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), we saw that we received a 200 status code, but the response and response headers were empty as well.

These are the errors in the console:

> `http://storage.googleapis.com/...`    Failed to load resource: Origin
>   `<origin>` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://storage.googleapis.com/...` Origin
>   `<origin>` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there a issue with the latest version of Safari and CORS?

Comment: When you get those CORS error messages, what are all the details about the response(s) that you see in the Network tab of Safari devtools? What are the response headers, and the response status code? Please copy those details out of Safari devtools and use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45803819/edit to edit/update your question to paste in those details. In particular, what value does the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header have?

Comment: And when you say you’re not getting a response to the OPTIONS, then what response are those CORS error messages for? Because you’re not going to get those messages unless the server has sent a response. If the server hasn’t sent a response, then the browser will log a different message than what the question shows. *“Failed to load resource”* doesn’t mean the browser didn’t get a response—instead it means the browser did get are response, but the browser is not allowing your frontend JavaScript code to access that response (because the origin value in Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn’t match)

Comment: You can’t really get a response with completely empty headers. You’re aware that after you open the Network tab, you need to reload the page, right? That is, you’re not going to see anything at all in the Network tab unless you reload. Maybe you can take a screenshot of what you’re actually examining in the Network tab, and post that as an update to the question?

Comment: I have a similar problem. When sending an OPTIONS request for CORS, a 403 is returned and error "Failed to load resource preflight response is not successful" is printed in console. This happens in Safari 10.1.2 but works perfectly fine in Safari 10.0.2.